# Bind Drop down Using Web Method (how to call web services in C#)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html-select, cascadingdropdown

I want to bind multiple drop down list and all drop down list are mutually dependent to each other.
Using Web method (Services URL).
Services Return type is `ExtensionDataObject` and i want to store this return type to List is it possible or not m not sure

But how can i bind this object into List.

ASPX

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var params = { UserId: 'approver01', WorkflowTypeCode: 4 };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "objectData": params }),
                    url: 'IP/Service.svc/getdata/GetCountriesName',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: BindCountry,
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });

                function BindCountry(response) {
                    $.each(response.d, function (key, value) {
                        appendString = "<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>";
                        $("#ddlCountry").append(appendString);
                    });
                }
                function ajaxError(response) {
                    alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
                }
            });
        </script>


<select id="ddlCountry" runat="server">
     <option value="0">--Select Country--</option>
</select>
 <select id="ddlCompany" runat="server">
      <option value="0">--Select Company--</option>
 </select>
 <select id="ddlDivision" runat="server">
      <option value="0">--Select Devision--</option>
 </select>
<select id="ddlLocation">
       <option value="0">--Select Location</option>
</select>
```

.CS code
Here my approach is to : creating object for service reference and then add to list and return list and calling through aspx Using j query URL but unable to do same.

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static List<CountryList> GetCountriesName(string UserID)
 { //Creating object for service reference.
   AlmaraiMasterDataService.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new AlmaraiMasterDataService.MasterDataServiceClient(); 
   List<CountryList> lst = new List<CountryList>();
   lst.Add(oClient.GetActiveCountries); //Error not able to add In List
   return lst;                                                               
 }
 public class CountryList
   {
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide detail of `Mymethod` on backend side?

Comment: @SelimYildiz i am Updating my question once again

Answer (score 0):

@nitish:As per my obeservation mymethod is the method in the jquery url
url: 'IP/Service.svc/getdata/Mymethod',
but actual webmethod name is GetCountriesName().I suggest try to change it in jquery url too.will help.

Comment: just for security region i modify such things

Comment: i am not able to add Country in List Item as i mention in my code and you can check my Updated code

Comment: var params = { UserId: 'approver01', WorkflowTypeCode: 4 }; you are passing 2 params from jquery ajax call but your webmethod has no parameters.plz check and let me know.bcoz i tried and its working now.like this  data: JSON.stringify({ UserID: 'approver01', WorkflowTypeCode: 4 }), and  [WebMethod]
        public static List<CountryList> GetCountriesName(string UserID, int WorkflowTypeCode)

Comment: i have added 2 parameters in my method but i am not able to add this object reference to List Item Please help me

Comment: oClient.GetActiveCountries() should return a List<CountryList> and u directly assign it to List<CountryList> lst;or u hv to use loop if oClient.GetActiveCountries() returns single item .if possible post ur oClient.GetActiveCountries()  code.

Comment: HAve you Image i have posted Please check once.

Comment: oClient.GetActiveCountries() give this method implementation

Comment: But after i am adding this into List where i am facing error i am not able to add oClient.GetActiveCountries()  into List .

Comment: List<CountryList> lst = new List<CountryList>();
            lst = oClient.GetActiveCountries(); try assigning like this

Comment: ```function BindCountry(response) {
                    $.each(response.d, function (key, value) {
                        //appendString = "<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>";
                        //$("#ddlCountry").append(appendString);
                         $("#ddlCountry").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CountryId).html(value.CountryName));  
                    });
                }``` change BindCountry() in aspx too.

Comment: i can not even bind service into list how can i call from aspx

Comment: please Recheck my Updated Question as i have added one image please see that image i am not able to add service object to <LIST>

Comment: then i can say it would be helpful if u provide the oClient.GetActiveCountries() implementation.